# DLL compiling : cl.exe [... ] /link /MACHINE:X86 -> fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'

Tags: dll, x86, 64-bit, cl.exe

so as said in the title I'm compiling my DLL with the `cl.exe` for x86 and using `/MACHINE:X86`

here my Makefile :

```
#Build DLL in DriverApp/bin/$(IntDir)
SRC  = src\DriverCore.cpp
OUT  = bin\DriverCore.dll

all: $(SRC)

DLL: $(SRC)
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe" /w $(SRC) /EHsc /link /DLL /MACHINE:X86 /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /OUT:$(OUT)
```

and the output don't make sense

```
PS C:\Users\ridap\Documents\GitHub\KNX-Communication-Analyser\src\Driver\DriverCore> nmake DLL

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.28.29910.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe" /w src\DriverCore.cpp /EHsc /link /DLL /MACHINE:X86 /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /OUT:bin\DriverCore.dll
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.28.29337 for x86  <-- so it's the cl for x86 !
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

DriverCore.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.28.29337.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:DriverCore.exe
/DLL
/MACHINE:X86
/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS
/OUT:bin\DriverCore.dll
DriverCore.obj
libcpmt.lib(uncaught_exception.obj) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

And the more stupid it gets when I change `/MACHINE:X64` with the same `cl.exe` for x86
So here, the `cl.exe` tell me that it's the cl for x86 and that I'm trying to compile for a x64 target...

```
PS C:\Users\ridap\Documents\GitHub\KNX-Communication-Analyser\src\Driver\DriverCore> nmake DLL

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.28.29910.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe" /w src\DriverCore.cpp /EHsc /link /DLL /MACHINE:X64 /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /OUT:bin\DriverCore.dll
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.28.29337 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

DriverCore.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.28.29337.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:DriverCore.exe
/DLL
/MACHINE:X64
/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS
/OUT:bin\DriverCore.dll
DriverCore.obj
DriverCore.obj : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

I can't find solution on internet about this behaviour plz help !

Comment: *libcpmt.lib* is *x64* lib. you use wrong path

Comment: @RbMm the error with *libcpmt.lib* only appear when using the cl.exe of ``` \HostX64\x86 \cl.exe``` and ```\HostX86\x86\cl.exe``` 
But when using the one of ```\HostX64\x64\cl.exe```, or ```\HostX86\x64\cl.exe ``` it's the same error but without mention of *libcmt.lib*

Comment: *module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'* - what here unclear ? *libcpmt.lib* is *x64* lib. but you try build *x86* *PE*. what is full path for *libcpmt.lib* ? look for this. instead try play with `HostX**\x**`

Comment: OK ! I didn't know what was *libcpmt.lib* ! So I changed ```$Env:lib``` with the path to x86 *libpcmt.lib* so i replace the envvars from x64 to x86.